# ImportError when running Runpython Excel on Windows

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to learn using xlwings. I tried running the python script from excel 2016, but it pop up error message.

Error Message:
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named hello

```
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

def world():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheet[0].range('A1').value = "Hello World"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j8pj.png)

Comment: Is your python file named hello.py?

Answer (score 0):

Is this all your code?
If so the likely error is that the module you imported is missing another module or has been changed, if not you need to put your code called "hello" into the inbuilt python library on your computer as it is looking for it in the wrong place.